# Bulk Update of SharePoint Group Properties?

Tags: groups, properties, bulk

Specifically, I am looking for a way to change the "Who can view the membership of the group?" setting for multiple groups.

Any built-in methods? or does it require custom code? Examples of custom code would be a big help...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would attack this via powershell, but I can't say that I have a script handy.  Otherwise it would be done in code or manually through the UI.

Comment: Thanks Mike, just looking for confirmation of the best approach. Code or UI is enough info for me to proceed. Not that I would turn away an example script... but really all I needed was some assurance I was on the right path.

Comment: If you have more than say 10-15 groups that have to be updated or if this is something you will need for the future (think consultants) then developing a script is very good.  At the same time, it wouldn't do you much good to spend hours developing a script if it were to take you 20 minutes to just manually update the groups.